# In a single link ahref link, how to control spacing between this wrapped link in mobile mode?

Tags: html, css

I have a single headline which is a link within a div tag.

```css
 h1.banner a { 
        display: inline; 
        font-size: 2rem; 
        margin: 0; 
        border: none;
        font-style: italic;
        }
```

```html
<a href="https://URL">text of link text of link text of link</a>
```

The line is OK and in mobile mode, appears as a single line but wraps around the edges to create a multiple lines single link. This is OK.

Here is the gap I’m referring to:

[image: gap]

However, the gaps between each line is quite much. Is there any code that I can add to make the gaps between the lines of single link?

Comment: `line-height` ?

Comment: Well I'm adding an example image of the space in question.. https://imgur.com/a/coKuXcZ

Comment: If you adding such image then put it in the code here. Also do you want that image inline with text or as a block?

Comment: My original question has the code just the text element is different

Comment: @gpl the image is an example of the result of my code above

Comment: @gpl ok done I edited my original question

Comment: @sd100 everything looking fine...........it is same line. Do you want gap between specific line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `line-height` property to specify the height of a line.

To reduce gap give values < 1 or 100%

To increase gap give values > 1 or 100%

Given number would be multiplied with the current line height of the text.